# string.contains is always returning true

Tags: string, boolean, contains

I made a program that takes a text file, stores the lines as strings in an array. Now I want to "filter" those entries of the array.

I am using the string.contains to see if each array entry has the substring "05/Aug".

For some reason, it is always returning true, when in fact, it should not.

Here is the file: http://www.santarosa.edu/~lmeade/weblog.txt

And here is my code:

```
for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
        boolean check = storestrings[i].contains("05/Aug");
        if(check = true){
            teststring[i] = storestrings[i];
            //System.out.print(storestrings[i]);
        }
        else{
            teststring[i] = null;

            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used assignment operator in the if statement instead of equality. It should be like this:

```
if(check == true){
    teststring[i] = storestrings[i];
    //System.out.print(storestrings[i]);
}
```

or simply

```
if (check) {
    teststring[i] = storestrings[i];
    //System.out.print(storestrings[i]);
}
```

In your code, when it reached check = true in the if statement, it assigns true to the check variable and returns true so the if condition always evaluates to true.